# What is causing color expressions to be highlighted in my VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS Code can't seem to figure this out even after an extensive google search. I'm making a Flutter project which uses `fromARGB()` method for background. It always gets highlighted like this:

[image]

This also happens with hex colour codes. Any idea how I may turn this highlighting off?

VS Code version: 1.78.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by the [`naumovs.color-highlight`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naumovs.color-highlight) extension.

A general tip for debugging VS Code problems to see if they're caused by an extension: First try reloading with extensions disabled to see if the problem still occurs with no extensions (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette). If it doesn't happen with all extensions disabled, reload VS Code with extensions enabled, and then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to find out what extension is causing the behaviour.